# How do you say "I am almost # (age)" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

When I am using Google translate on "*I am almost 18*", I get:

> Ich bin fast 18.
>   Ich bin beinahe 18.

Are this sentences correct? What is most used? Are there any other popular forms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, those sentences are correct. Most used is the first sentence

> Ich bin fast 18.

The other sentence sounds somewhat awkward. *Beinahe* has - imho - a connotation that means that there had almost something happened.

> Beinahe hätte ich den Zug verpasst. (*I almost missed the train.*)

So, I'd recommend not to use *beinahe*.

A typical alternative is

> Ich werde bald 18.

Comment: `Ich werde bald 18` (I'll be 18 soon) is good. However, I don't agree with your caveat against using `beinahe`. Translations never map perfectly, but if `fast = almost` then you can say that `beinahe = nearly`. You can say `I am nearly 18` and likewise you can say `Ich bin beinahe 18`. I see it as a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Of course you can say *beinahe 18*, haven't said, that is does not work. But it's not that common. And luckily, Google back me up. In English I think *nearly* and *almost* are interchangeably, in German ... in theory absolutely, in practice rarely. In the end, it's just a personal opinion, and therefore *imho*

Comment: Und ganz nebenbei habe ich *Ich bin beinahe 18* noch NIE von einem Muttersprachler gehört. Vllt ist das auch regional bedingt, und woanders wird das eher gesagt.

Comment: I believe we had this discussion before ("am/im Flughafen"). The only criterion for me is my ear and I confess that I care f*ck all for what Google says :)  So, I imagine a 17 year-old person telling me `Ich bin beinahe 18`. Does it sound odd to my ears? No. Good enough for me then :)

Comment: *"Ich bin beinhahe 18"* ist eine etwas gehobenere Ausdrucksweise. Man hört das vielleicht deshalb etwas seltener.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel from own experience as now 18 yr. old. nope. I did not use "beinahe" in combination with my age. in general, if asked about my age i only replied "fast 18" or "bald 18"

Comment: @Em1: In English, "I'm not quite 18" also expresses that you are nearly or almost 18, but like "beinahe" it is more about the negative side, not being 18 yet.

Comment: "Beinahe" - hell, it works...

Comment: Aside from that, a merger would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both are correct. A somewhat more verbose, but also correct variant, would be to say

> Ich bin fast/beinahe 18 Jahre alt.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a third alternative:

> Ich bin so gut wie 18 [Jahre alt]

Comment: IMO this would be possible, but not very common.

Comment: @0x6d64 Depending on context, this can be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Um noch eine weitere Variante hinzuzufügen:

> Ich werde in Kürze 18.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn wir schon Varianten sammeln, hier meine:

> Ich bin bald 18

Answer (score 0):

> Ich bin beinahe 18

would tend to mean that you barely missed being 18. For example, you wanted to watch an age limited movie in the cinema, but they didn't let you in because you are not *quite* 18 but only *almost* 18.

> Ich bin fast 18

would tend to mean you are approaching 18 and will hit the goal soon. Like you didn't watch a movie because it is for kids and you are almost 18.

Answer (score 0):

Among children,

> Ich bin schon 7 einhalb.

is often used.