# Difference between "fast" and "beinahe"

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes I have a preference for using either "fast" or "beinahe", but I didn't manage to pin down exactly why. In all cases I could think of, these words mean the same. Or do they?

Comment: Related [How do you say “I am almost # (age)” in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4308/how-do-you-say-i-am-almost-age-in-german). Possibly even a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words *beinahe* and *fast* are very similar. There are many contexts in which they can be used interchangeably. There are some others where they cannot be interchanged.

#### Hypotheses

- The German Wiktionary mentions several examples for [beinahe](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/beinahe) and [fast](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast). The former examples are more emotional, while the latter carry a neutral tone.
- *beinahe* ist for a change in situation, *fast* is for a fixed state
- depending on the emphasis you put in *fast*, it can carry a neutral tone or get emotional

#### Examples

> Das Glas ist fast übergelaufen.
>
> Das Glas ist beinahe übergelaufen.

The two words are interchangeable here.

> Der Zug hätte mich beinahe überfahren.
>
> Der Zug hätte mich fast überfahren.

The two words are interchangeable here.

> [*]Das Glas ist beinahe voll.
>
> Das Glas ist fast voll.

The sentence with "beinahe voll" sounds unnatural, constructed. This may be because "beinahe" is usually not used for expressing a fixed state.

> [*]Es dauert noch beinahe eine Woche, bis ich meinen Führerschein bekomme.
>
> Es dauert noch fast eine Woche, bis ich meinen Führerschein bekomme.

When measuring things, *beinahe* doesn't sound right.

> [*]In beinahe einer Woche bekomme ich meinen Führerschein.
>
> In fast einer Woche bekomme ich meinen Führerschein.

When measuring things, *beinahe* doesn't sound right.

> Ich bin schon beinahe 15 Jahre alt.
>
> Ich bin schon fast 15 Jahre alt.

Using *beinahe* sounds unnatural (but only a little). This may be because your age is something you cannot influence.

Comment: Die Unterscheidung, was da emotionaler sein soll, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen und auch nicht die Gewissheit, dass, selbst wenn es so wäre, dies nicht zufällig ist. Man sieht hier oft ein Antwortverhalten, wenn nach Bedeutungsunterschieden gefragt wird, dass die Leute aus Hilfsbereitschaft und Ehrgeiz sich irgendwas zusammenreimen, wovon man vorher nie gehört hat. Es muss gar keinen Unterschied geben - diese Möglichkeit sollte man nicht voreilig ausschließen.

Comment: Hmmm, für mich klingt "das Glas ist fast voll" nach einer neutralen Aussage (vielleicht nicht immer, aber doch überwiegend). Wohingegen "das Glas ist beinahe voll" dramatischer klingt, weniger abgeschlossen, mit dem Unterton "da passiert noch was".

Comment: @RolandIllig definitiv. »Das Glas ist fast voll«, wenn es einfach nur fast voll ist (und das möglicherweise schon recht lange ist und eventuell auch noch lange so bleiben wird). »Das Glas ist beinahe voll«, wenn es gerade befüllt wird und »gleich voll« (gleich = in kurzer Zeit) ist.

Comment: Huiuiui, das wird kompliziert, aber ich glaube, ich verstehe langsam, was _beinahe_ wirklich heißt. Wenn die Erkenntnisfindung hier abgeschlossen ist, ergänze ich es im Wiktionary.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Und ich behaupte, dass der Kontext und die Betonung darüber entscheiden, wie neutral oder dramatisch die Aussage ist. Sprich mal beides auf Band - ehm - als MP3 ins Micro und betone dann das andere so wie das eine und höre es Dir nochmal an.

Answer (score 1):

Both are quite similar in meaning. If it is a number, only "fast" fits  ("wir haben fast 1000 Fragebögen zurückbekommen" for 973) while both can be used for something that can not be quantified ("Ich war so in meine Lektüre vertieft, dass ich beinahe/fast die Station zum Aussteigen verpasst hätte").
However, I can't give a reason for that, it is just my own feeling for what is appropriate.

Comment: even "wir haben beinahe 1000 Fragebögen zurückbekommen" is perfectly fine

Comment: @Tommylee2k yes, but to me it has more a notion of "we almost got the 1000 questionnaires back, but they all got lost in the last moment" having less emphasis on the quantity side of things

Comment: "Wir haben beinahe 40° und dann geht der Kühlschrank kaputt!" Man sieht hier oft ein Antwortverhalten, wenn nach Bedeutungsunterschieden gefragt wird, dass die Leute aus Hilfsbereitschaft und Ehrgeiz sich irgendwas zusammenreimen, wovon man vorher nie gehört hat. Es muss gar keinen Unterschied geben - diese Möglichkeit sollte man nicht voreilig ausschließen.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich reime mir da nichts zusammen, es entspricht tatsächlich meinem Sprachgefühl. "beinahe 1000" klingt in meinen Ohren einfach unpassend.  Beachte dabei auch den letzten Satz meiner Antwort.

Comment: Das macht zusammenreimen eben aus, dass es auf nichts als Deinem Sprachgefühl basiert. Die Seite handelt von der dt. Sprache, nicht vom Sprachgefühl Volker Landgrafs oder von meinem.  "If it is a number, only "fast" fits" ist dagegen eine normative Aussage.

Comment: @userunknown In Fällen wie diesem, wo 2 Begriffe sich entweder gar nicht oder nur in Nuancen unterscheiden, wirst Du aber oftmals nicht mehr als das bekommen *können*. Falls sich dann aus dem Sprachgefühl von hinreichend vielen Antwortern eine Mehrheitsmeinung herauskristallisiert, darf diese als zutreffend interpretiert werden. Wichtig ist hierbei IMHO, dass die Antwort klar als vom Sprachgefühl kommend gekennzeichnet ist, um sie von einer lexikalisch recherchierten unterscheiden zu können - das habe ich in meiner Antwort auch getan.

Comment: P.S. Falls es mehrere "Häufungspunkte" gibt, kann dies auf regionale Bedeutungsunterschiede hinweisen, ansonsten liegt die Vermutung nahe, dass es  tatsächlich keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Begriffen gibt.

Comment: Nein, das könnte man allenfalls, wenn es zu jeder Frage hunderte Antworten gäbe und wenn diese unabhängig voneinander wären. Da es den Anderen mit dem Wunsch helfen zu können und einen Unterschied zu finden ähnlich geht, wie dem, der sich zuerst einen Unterschied einbildet und notdürftig bebildert, wird diesem oft freudig gefolgt und kritische Gegenfragen gar nicht erst gestellt, erstens, und zweitens heißt "häufiger" in der Sprache keineswegs "richtig". "Fast ein Dutzend" finde ich etwa 10x so oft wie "Beinahe ein Dutzend" - das sagt nur etwas über die Häufigkeit aus, nichts zur Korrektheit.